# Convert to nested class format

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given something like this:

```
namespace Mystuff
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public class Bar
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In Rosyln if I wanted to get the symbol that represents `Bar` I can do something like this:

```
var barSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyStuff.Foo+Bar");
```

But this will not work:

```
var barSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyStuff.Foo.Bar");
```

You have to have the `+` to represent that `Bar` is nested in `Foo`. But if all I have is the string `MyStuff.Foo.Bar` (because it comes from somewhere else where it's got the name of `Bar`), is there any reliable way to get from `MyStuff.Foo.Bar` to `MyStuff.Foo+Bar` if you don't know *a priori* whether `MyStuff.Foo.Bar` is a nested class inside of `Foo` or a non-nested class inside of the namespace `MyStuff.Foo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Class .GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110744/nested-class-gettype)

Comment: @MethodMan: Not a duplicate. This is a rosyln question and the issue is how to convert from dot notation to the `+` notation needed for `GetTypeByMetadataName`

Comment: You basically want to parse & resolve that name as a C# typename (but ignoring namespace imports), not as a CLR (metadata) name.  I don't know if the semantic model has an API for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look that up yourself:

Split the name on `.`, then, starting with `compilation.SourceModule.GlobalNamespace`, loop through each part and call `GetMembers(name)` on the current symbol to get the `ITypeOrNamespaceSymbol` with that name.

Comment: Hmmm....But would that work if a namespace had a dot in it? So if the namespace was `MyStuff.Foo` then presumably I won't find anything when trying to `GetMembers("MyStuff")`? Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: @MattBurland: No; that's a nested namespace and will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, just playing around with that and it does appear (although I really never thought about this), if you do something like `namespace foo.bar`, it really does create a namespace `foo` with a namespace `bar` in it. So that ought to work. Thanks.